# Prove that AF=AB

Tags: circles

**Question** -

Draw a circle with centre O .choose a point A and cut off chord AB,BC,CD,DE,EF each equal to radius .prove that AF=AB

**My try** -

I know this is very simple question but I am not getting..
I tried angle chasing , try to show some congruence but none of them work...any hints  ?

Answer (score 1):

If you picture a circle centred at $O$, and pick a point $A$ along the radius of the circle and cut off a chord equal to the radius at another point $B$ , and join $B$ with $O$ you will end up in an equilateral triangle of side equal to the Radius of the circle.
Carrying on this process will lead you to a regular hexagon inscribed in the circle of side equal to the radius of the circle 
This would easily prove any side equal to any other leading to :
$$AF= AB$$

Comment: We have to first show that AF=AB then show that it is regular hexagon...yu did opposite direction which is wrong...

Comment: Does it really matter which you prove first? You end up in the same thing don't you?!

Comment: Besides, where is the question asking to prove it to be a regular hexagon, may I ask?